# JKS file - do I need key-store?

Tags: android, android-studio, jks

I have JKS file and need to compile app. But I don't have keystore file from original computer. Is it possible to compile signed app with this JKS?

And is there any app which checks whether I am using the right password for this JKS file?

Comment: All you need is the exact jks (key store file) that you used to sign your app the first time; so if you have it, you should be able to compile again; if you don't, you are unlucky!

Comment: ok so I have my jks in folder of my app. How should I add this file to "global" keystore on my system? (c:documents and settings\user\...). And how can I check, if I am using the right password for this jks?

Comment: @peter what you mean  by you dont have a keystore file. is it that you have it before and compiled app with it and uploaded to store now you want to do the same app with jsk file let me clear please

Comment: Basically, go to your IDE and select Generate Signed APK; then browse to where you have your jks stored in your file system instead of creating a new one!

Comment: I guys, sorry for "stupid" questions from my side, I am bit new with this. I thought I must have appropriate file in C:\Documents and Settings\User\.android, I see there files with .keystore - so I thought I must import it to my system somehow. In android studio I see passwrord keytore password and key password. Is there any way how can I check both passwords without compiling app - because I don't remember password and I need to try more passwrods, but with android studio I must wait until "password error message" if it is wrong - so I need faster method for this. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Copy the same android key file X.jks to your pc while generating apk choosing existing keystore navigate to your X.jks put the same jks password once and select alias now Click finish.

> Your apk will be generated with the same key